# NullPointer in Andorid.button.OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm a new to Android, I'm trying to learn Android by some tutorials. Here is the error in logcat when I try to get start with button.I think the problem is these 2 buttons are not found by method findViewById. How can I fix it.
error:

```
  03-18 00:57:46.964: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cs656/com.example.cs656.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

and here is the activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button log_in;
    private Button register;
    private Button.OnClickListener Button_Listener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            setTitle("kkkkkkkkkkkk");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        log_in = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        log_in.setOnClickListener(Button_Listener);

        register = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button2);

    }   
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button android:id ="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button android:id ="@+id/log_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log In" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which of 'register' or 'log_in' buttons do you expect to get when calling 'findViewById(android.R.id.button1)'?

Answer (score 2):

Change this lines

```
  log_in = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
  register = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
```

to

```
  log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_in);
  register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
```

Your id's are mismatch in xml and in java file.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my question. Looks like I made a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  log_in = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
  register = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
```

to

```
  log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_in);
  register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
```

The `android.R.id.button1` tries to search in android default xmls and not in the xml that you created.
Also, use the same id as declared in the xml.

Comment: This is the not right answer of OP's question.